# Typescript class properties initialization order

Tags: typescript

Say I have a class such as:

```
class MyClass {
   private readonly prop1 = "prop1"
   private readonly prop2: string

   constructor(
     prop2 = "defaultProp2",
     private readonly prop3 = "defaultProp3"
   ) {
     this.prop2 = prop2
   }

   ...
}
```

What's the variables initialization order?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you compile to `ES5` you can see the order things are initialized in when the code is down compiled (and  the order is consistent when native classes are used).

```
var MyClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MyClass(prop2, prop3) {
        if (prop2 === void 0) { prop2 = "defaultProp2"; }
        if (prop3 === void 0) { prop3 = "defaultProp3"; }
        this.prop3 = prop3;
        this.prop1 = "prop1";
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
```

So the order is:

1. Constructor field shorthand
2. Property initializers
3. Constructor body.

Comment: Thanks! And what about ES6?

Comment: @LppEdd I checked, the order is consistent across targets (as I would expect it to be)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I've seen the TS playground only seems to target ES5

Comment: @LppEdd yeah that true. I had to test locally

Comment: Why is the order such that constructor shorthand is first, but body last and the class fields inserted in the middle? /edit: Oh, because if I want to assign to a property in a constructor, it mus be initialized first. Makes sense.